# VLC breaks when opening preferences (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu, vlc-media-player

When I open VLC (2.2.2) and press CTRL+P or open preferences from the menu bar, VLC breaks in the following way:

The media still plays, minimization and maximization still work, but the menu bar disappears, no buttons on the interface work, and I can't close the program via the X button.

```
$ vlc

VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)

[000000000250b148] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.

QVariantMap DBusMenuExporterDBus::getProperties(int, const QStringList&) const: Condition failed: action

(((same QVariant message repeated over 10 times)))

[00007fa4bcc33518] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  384.90  Tue Sep 19 17:04:31 PDT 2017 for hardware decoding.

(((CTRL+C)))

QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

I removed and reinstalled VLC with apt-get, but the problem persists. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: The problem went away. I'm not sure what made it go away. The only changes I remember: I opened a different file, and I opened `Customize Interface...` before attempting to open preferences again.